# LINQ to SQL different output when convert SQL query to LINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, linq

I'am wondering about the output when converting SQL query to LINQ:

```
select coalesce(SUM(cdin_ActMortgageAmnt),0)  
from CRM.dbo.CDIndex,CRM.dbo.company  
where comp_companyid=cdin_companyid 
  and comp_idcust like '%10319%' 
  and cdin_goodscategory ='Financed' 
  and cdin_Deleted is null
  and cdin_startunstufdate is not null 
  and cdin_Status='InProgress'
```

The LINQ query i implement is:

```
 var ACTMORTGAGE= (from com in db.Companies
                       join cd in db.CDIndexes on com.Comp_CompanyId
                       equals cd.cdin_CompanyId
                    where
                       cd.cdin_Status == "InProgress" &&
                       com.Comp_IdCust==c.Comp_IdCust&&
                       cd.cdin_startunstufdate != null &&
                       cd.cdin_Deleted == null
                    select new { ActAmnt=  cd.cdin_ActMortgageAmnt });
```

Then i do the summation like this:

```
decimal ACT = (decimal)ACTMORTGAGE.AsEnumerable().Sum(o =>o.ActAmnt);
```

The output for the native SQL query is : 0.000000

While in the `decimal ACT` generated by LINQ query  is: 0 which appeared without decimal points.

i'm sure that there's nothing wrong with my LINQ query, but why LINQ query give me different output from native SQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMO they are practically the same. 
if you are sure that ActAmnt is decimal then you can view as much decimals as you want with

> [Decimal.ToString("0.0000000")](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0b22a4x2(v=vs.110).aspx)

Your SQL query returns biggest precision because probably you have declared your columns as DECIMAL(12,5) in your table

Comment: I figured out SQL server i found that cdin_ActMortgageAmnt is declared as numaric(24,6) but in visual studio it's :
public Nullable<decimal> cdin_ActMortgageAmnt { get; set; }

Comment: @faresAyyad we are talking about the same thing. :)

Comment: @faresAyyad yes, so you can accept my answer because it is correct.